# While statement in LinkedList Cycle -- Leetcode problem

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```java
    /**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * class ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     ListNode next;
     *     ListNode(int x) {
     *         val = x;
     *         next = null;
     *     }
     * } 
     */
    public class Solution {
        public boolean hasCycle(ListNode head) {
            
            ListNode slow = head;
            ListNode fast = head;
            
            if (fast == null || slow == null) {
                
                return false;
            }
                
            while (fast.next.next != null && slow.next != null) {
                
                slow = slow.next;
                fast = fast.next.next;
                
                if (slow == fast) {
                    return true;
                } 
            }
            return false;
        }               
    }
```

The above code is for the LinkedList cycle leetcode question. My code (Specifically, the while loop) throws a nullpointerexception. Could someone please explain? I'm confused specifically because "`while (fast != null && fast.next != null)`" do not throw exceptions.

Comment: Your code throws null pointer exception especially when ```fast.next == null```, because you have in the while cycle ```fast.next.next```. If you check ```fast.next != null```, then the while cycle finish before calling null.next. It might help: ```while (fast.next != null && fast.next.next != null && slow.next != null) {```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a case: a linked list that has no cycle and 3 elements.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

At initialization, you will have:

```
slow
 |
 v
fast
 |
 v
 1   -> 2 -> 3
```

After the first iteration, you will have:

```
     slow  fast
      |     |
      v     v
 1 -> 2 ->  3
```

Now, your fast.next will be null and hence, it does not point to any object and it does not have next value. So, it will throw null pointer exception.